# Wordpress Category Page display category and subcategory in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm stuck with a seemingly simple Wordpress issue. I have a client who wants their category pages to display posts filtered down by category and sub category, so for example

`www.mysite.com/category/travel` should display all travel posts, while `www.mysite.com/category/travel/japan` should display a further filtered list of posts with the category of Japan (which in itself is a child category of travel).

I though that this would be quite simple to do, but I'm not having any luck. Could any body help?

Comment: Categories are already hierarchical by default in Wordpress. Tags aren't.

Answer (score 1):

you can create category name "japan" with parent category "travel" from post category configuration section